# Trying to implement an indexer with a property in C# for COM Interop

Tags: c#, com

In DAO Recordsets there's the ability to access the current row in the Recordset object by typing something like

```
someRecordset.Fields("SomeColumnName")
```

but you can also get the total columns like this

```
someRecordset.Fields.Count
```

Is there anyway in C# where i can do the same behavior.  I already have an indexer for the method i'm writing so that i can access a Dictionary<string, object> by:

```
MyClass.Fields("someKey")
```

or by

```
MyClass["someKey"]
```

But I have no way forward to implement the same type of behavior as

```
MyClass.Fields.SomePropertyOfTheIndexedObject
```

Do note i am using the COM standard with the UnmanagedExports package to modernize an old library and i don't want to rewrite the main program... i want to avoid changing anything about the calling application if it is possible.

Comment: Are you saying that you're using COM interop to consume DAO components and you want to know how to access the `Fields` indexed property? Or are you asking how to implement indexed properties in a C# class? Please clarify.

Comment: @madreflection I am asking how to implement indexed properties in a C# class (if that's possible)
I was just using a DAO component as an example for what i want to do

Comment: The `someRecordset.Fields` property returns a whole new object, also called [`Fields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/fields-object-reference-dao), that has an indexer of its own and some other properties. You could do the same.

Comment: I don't quite get your first example but a proper COM indexer looks like `excelApp.Range["A1"];`.  Note the _square brackets_.   C# has had this COM support [since VS2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-use-indexed-properties-in-com-interop-rogramming).  Prior to that you had to call the underlying `get` method passing in the index.  Nowadays, as far as C# programmers are concerned this get method is hidden by the index _property_ that takes an argument.

Comment: @GSerg I have had no luck with passing an object from inside another object.  The main program is vb6 and even though the .dll that is generated (C#) can have the Fields object accessed, there is no such luck with vb6, it throws "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" when hitting "MyClass.Fields("somedata")"

Comment: @MickyD that works fine, what the issue is has to do with returning a property from the indexer is not possible. C# does not support properties in indexers or multiple getters

Comment: @SLWW You should have `public Fields Fields { get; }` in `MyClass`, and then `public class Fields` with an indexer.

Comment: @GSerg I tried that; exactly that actually, and it didn't work :(